# Google doesn't tell me which waypoint is wrong (Javascript API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When Google returns a NOT_FOUND response to a direction request with waypoints, the documentation says

```
NOT_FOUND indicates at least one of the locations specified in the requests
          origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded.
```

But it doesn't tell me which one is invalid...

I realise I could then attempt to geocode each address individually to find the bad address, but that is wasting a lot of geocoding requests, given I have about 20 waypoints, and given Google could just tell me which one failed...

Is there a way to do this?

My fallback is to geocode the addresses before I save them, however I'd prefer not to do this, if I can get google to tell me which waypoint failed.

Normally, the response comes back with `warnings`, and I thought the bad address may come back in that, however I think that only happens if a route can be built in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Warning` items are intended to display information when a route has been found, you are right. For example, it is telling that the `walking` directions mode results are in beta.

Sample: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charle,MA&mode=walking`

For the problem you depicted (waypoint is not found), the response of the webservice is really short. Sample call with a non-working waypoint:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Chle,MA
```

Result:

```
{
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

The google maps Directions API is not currently helping for your case, and you also cannot try to geocode all your waypoint at once. Furthermore, the geocode api will throw an error if you exceed 5 simultaneous requests, so you initial workaround idea may be limited.

As a workaround (but not perfect, as the results between this service and gmaps service can be different), you could try to use other geocoding services, such as the one provided by OpenStreetMap: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Search

You still have to do it one-by-one, but you won't be getting a "query limit exceeded" error.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I'll have to do client-side geocoding for address as it is inputted by the user. That way I can get round the waypoint limit too, when drawing directions on a map!

Comment: If you are doing client-side geocoding when typing that should be ok, but not if you do it after all the input have been filled